# rmarkdown renders Rmd file as PDF with code and plots in wrong order

Tags: r

I'm using the [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) library to convert an Rmd file with code and plots to a PDF file, which I do with these commands:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("test.Rmd", "pdf_document")
```

Here is my test.Rmb file:

````
Title
========================================================

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring web pages (click the **Help** toolbar button for more details on using R Markdown).

When you click the **Knit HTML** button a web page will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

# cars

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

# mtcars

```{r}
summary(mtcars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

[This is the HTML result from that Rmd file.](http://jsfiddle.net/krb6E/embedded/result/) When I make the PDF, rmarkdown adds page breaks by pushing plots that can't fit on the current page to the next one. [This is the resultant PDF.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/224731356/Test-pdf)

As you can see, the first plot can't fit on the first page, so it gets bumped to the second. That's fine, but then code that comes *after* the first plot is bumped back to the first page, which makes no sense to me. The only way I've figured out how to avoid this problem is to add manual `$\pagebreak$` LaTeX commands all over the place to prevent this behavior.

Is there a better way to stop rmarkdown from moving code that comes *after* plots *before* those plots?

Comment: You've asked on the wrong [se] site. There is nothing statistical here. Try on [so].

Comment: My generated PDF has the mtcars summary after the plot (i.e. the behaviour you want, not what's in your output). I'm running `rmarkdown_0.1.93`.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to rmarkdown 0.2.04 (from the GitHub repo) and that fixed the problem. If you want to write up your solution as an answer, I can accept it.